# Multiple Models in Django-filter 1.1.0

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-filter

I'd like to implement a filter for the end user of the site, so that they can filter by price, rating, gender and location.

The problem here is that price and rating are stored in the models class "comment" and the location and gender in the models class "adventure".

In the class "comment" the "adventure" is referenced by a foreign key.

How can I use Django-filter 1.1.0 in my filters.py to address both models "comment" and "adventure" that reference each other, to filter according to the above mentioned arguments?

Here is my code that works, but only filters the class "adventure". How can I extend this code to also filter by the foreign referenced arguments to return the matching adventures?

**filters.py**

```
import django_filters

class AdventureFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
      class Meta:
            model = Adventure
            fields = {
            'gender',
            'location',
            }
```

**models.py**

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    verfasser = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    related_adventure = models.ForeignKey(Adventure, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='comments')
    rating_choices = (
                      (1, '1 Stern'),
                      (2, '2 Sterne'),
                      (3, '3 Sterne'),
                      (4, '4 Sterne'),
                      (5, '5 Sterne')
    )       
    Rating = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, choices=rating_choices,blank=False, default=0)
    verfasst_am = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, blank=True, null=True)
    heading = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True,null=True, help_text="100 Zeichen")
    ratingtext= models.TextField(max_length=400, blank=True, null=True,help_text="400 Zeichen")

    price = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, help_text="Deine Ausgaben (pro Kopf) bei diesem Adventure", blank=True)



class Adventure(models.Model):
    adventure_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    place = PlacesField(blank=False)
    location_CHOICES = (
            ('IN', 'indoor'),
            ('OUT', 'outdoor'),
            ('INOUT', 'indoor and outdoor'),
    )
    location = models.CharField(
            max_length=10,
            choices=lokation_CHOICES,
    )


    gender_CHOICES = (
            ('male', 'male'),
            ('female', 'female'),
            (EGAL, 'egal'),
    )
    gender= models.CharField(
            max_length=9,
            choices=geschlecht_CHOICES,
            default=EGAL,
    )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an example from [the docs](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/usage.html):

```
class ProductFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    price = django_filters.NumberFilter()
    price__gt = django_filters.NumberFilter(name='price', lookup_expr='gt')
    price__lt = django_filters.NumberFilter(name='price', lookup_expr='lt')

    release_year = django_filters.NumberFilter(name='release_date', lookup_expr='year')
    release_year__gt = django_filters.NumberFilter(name='release_date', lookup_expr='year__gt')
    release_year__lt = django_filters.NumberFilter(name='release_date', lookup_expr='year__lt')

    manufacturer__name = django_filters.CharFilter(lookup_expr='icontains')

    class Meta:
        model = Product
```

There are two main arguments for filters:

- > name: The name of the model field to filter on. You can traverse
  > “relationship paths” using Django’s __ syntax to filter fields on a
  > related model. ex, manufacturer__name.
- > lookup_expr: The field lookup to use when filtering. Django’s __
  > syntax can again be used in order to support lookup transforms. ex,
  > year__gte.

**Notice the "__" chaining and I think you can use it directly without doing this explicit stuff inside fields = []**

Comment: Hi @Medo tareq, the "stable" docs are actually out of date. The "master" docs are current. e.g., `name` is now `field_name`.

Answer (score 2):

Write `fields = {'gender','location',}` as `fields = {'gender','location','comments__price', 'comments__Rating'}`.